# Upgrade HANA: SAP HANA Studio does not detect installed components

Tags: installation, sap-hana

I am trying to install SPS11 on top of SPS09 of SAP HANA

As stated in the documentation I tried in SAP HANA Studio:

```
> Right click on system
> Lifecycle Management
> Plattform Lifecycle Management
> Check for SAP HANA Components Updates
```

Which results in the Error

```
Could not detect the installed components on system <db name>
```

Any suggestions?

Pls not also that the service HDB Deamon is in status initializing

Answer (score 0):

before analyzing that, my recommendation: try running the upgrade with a non-resident hdblcm on the command line. See the SAP Help [on picking the right LCM](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/50/45ee4fef1842afb8d229389f3f698d/content.htm?frameset=/en/7c/afdaebf2694dbeb727cd50ee26ffd3/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/aa/c4bed2390045f59dd8fdeab3ffafb3/plain.htm&node_id=16)